# What does this string mean in the palette argument for seaborn scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

From [seaborn gallery - scatter plots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/different_scatter_variables.html),

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

# Load the example iris dataset
diamonds = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")

# Draw a scatter plot while assigning point colors and sizes to different
# variables in the dataset
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6.5, 6.5))
sns.despine(f, left=True, bottom=True)
clarity_ranking = ["I1", "SI2", "SI1", "VS2", "VS1", "VVS2", "VVS1", "IF"]
sns.scatterplot(x="carat", y="price",
                hue="clarity", size="depth",
                palette="ch:r=-.2,d=.3_r",
                hue_order=clarity_ranking,
                sizes=(1, 8), linewidth=0,
                data=diamonds, ax=ax)
```

What does this cryptic string `"ch:r=-.2,d=.3_r"` mean?

The only reference I can find is on [seaborn.color_palette](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.color_palette.html#seaborn.color_palette)'s doc, saying that

> ```
> Other options:
>   name of matplotlib cmap, 'ch:<cubehelix arguments>', 'hls', 'husl', or a list 
>   of colors in any format matplotlib accepts
> ```

But still cannot find anything in `matplotlib` doc.

So, what does it mean exactly? So far I only know the suffix `_r` means 'reverse' of hues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"ch:r=-.2,d=.3_r"` syntax is seaborn specific. So no wonder there is nothing about it in the matplotlib docs.

Possible options of `<cubehelix arguments>` in `'ch:<cubehelix arguments>'` can 
 implicitely be deduced from the [`seaborn.cubehelix_palette`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.cubehelix_palette.html#seaborn.cubehelix_palette) documentation.

This provides arguments like

> ```
> start : float, 0 <= start <= 3
>           The hue at the start of the helix.
> rot : float
>           Rotations around the hue wheel over the range of the palette.
> gamma : float 0 <= gamma
>           Gamma factor to emphasize darker (gamma < 1) or lighter (gamma > 1) colors.
> hue : float, 0 <= hue <= 1
>           Saturation of the colors.
> dark : float 0 <= dark <= 1
>           Intensity of the darkest color in the palette.
> light : float 0 <= light <= 1
>           Intensity of the lightest color in the palette.
> ```

You can use those in the string like

```
"ch:rot=-0.2,dark=0.3"
```

and in order to shorten this, using only the first letter is sufficient

```
"ch:r=-0.2,d=0.3"
```

Note that it is not possible to select the number of colors through this string mini language.

Comment: I don't think you can use the mini-language to define the number of colours. You would need to send `n_colors` as a separate `kwarg` I think. The relevant bit of code to parse the string is here: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/d00d07109e2b7d286ddb113bfe82410088f9e508/seaborn/palettes.py#L991